# Simpler way to compare pairs of bools?

Tags: c#, comparison, boolean

Let's say I have the following bools:

- isA
- isB
- isC
- isExistingA
- isExistingB
- isExistingC

When isA, isB, or isC is true, if all of the true bools' corresponding isExisting bools are also true, I want to do something. If isA, isB, or isC is false, then its corresponding isExisting bool does not matter.

Here's what I came up with:

```
if ((isA || isB || isC)
    && ((!isA || isExistingA)
    && (!isB || isExistingB)
    && (!isC || isExistingC)))
{
    // do something
}
```

I apparently can't think today and was wondering if there are simpler ways to express this.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, although `&&` is associative, so you don't need the extra parens around the second and third ones.

Comment: @Neil: I think the extra parens make it more readable.

Comment: Also, @John Straka: The way you used multiple lines and indentation makes the statement much easier to read :)

Comment: The missing operator is [implies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.modeling.logicaloperations.implies.aspx).  Hardly seems worth adding.

Comment: I generally group them into methods to make the `if` statement more readable when they get that complex.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not a fan of the operator on start of next line style, but surely the indentation on the subsequent lines is wrong since the operator should be indented inside the extra parens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha can simplify boolean equations, try this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28A%20%7C%7C%20B%20%7C%7C%20C%29%20&%20%28%28~A%20%7C%7C%20C%29%20&&%20%28~B%20%7C%7C%20D%29%20&&%20%28~C%20%7C%7C%20E%29%29%29)

However in my opinion don't worry about this too much, it's more important to keep your if statements clean and readable than to worry about compactness or performance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the requirement that although only one *isX* variable has to be true, all *isX* variables have to be examined. So I don't think you can write a statement with less "comparisons".

I think your current solution is the shortest form, but if I were to read that code without an explanation I would probably not understand it without looking twice (I assume though that the actual names are more descriptive, perhaps making more sense to a reader).

Comment: I agree, it's a bit obtuse. It makes a bit more sense with the business names though.